# How to make shape like this using border radius?

Tags: css, css-shapes

What i have made so far is here http://jsfiddle.net/cmRHp/1/

```
<div class="tv">13.3"</div>
```

and i want to make exactly like this

[image]

Comment: I don't think those are rounded borders.

Answer (score 3):

Those aren't actual rounded borders, so you probably have to use 2 elements.

```css
.tv {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font: bold 300%/3.6 sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px 70px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px 70px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px 70px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px 70px;
}
.tv-inner {
  background: black;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 70px 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 70px 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 70px 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 70px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tv">
  <div class="tv-inner">13.3"</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cmRHp/6/

Comment: Why not simply use pseudo-elements? IE7 doesn't support border-radius anyway.